# xcode install doesn't work from teminal

Tags: xcode, command-line-tool

So i'm trying to install the command line tool for xcode, i keep hearing to this 
`xcode-select --install` so I get the following output.

```
   xcode-select --install
    Usage: xcode-select -print-path
       or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
       or: xcode-select -version
    Arguments:
       -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
       -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
       -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

I have noticed that in my friend's comp, it's working [fine](http://cl.ly/image/2V3c0p0g2I31).

so what's wrong? do I need to switch the path??